# vim process memory consumption increase with time

Tags: vimrc, installing

Folks,

I am running my `vim-8.1.1` compiled in my debian stretch system. The `vim` process slowly eats up to 40% of my system memory in about 4-5hours. No big files opened. ~4 tabs opened (each with 2 split panes). I am having hard time troubleshooting. Could someone shed some light?

Configure options:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/VIM/ --disable-darwin --enable-python3interp=yes --with-vim-name=vem --with-modified-by=XXX --with-compiledby=xxx --with-python3-command
```

Enables options:

```
~~> vem --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Sep 21 2018 16:51:39)
Included patches: 1
Modified by XXX
Compiled by xxx
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
-balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
-browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +timers
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +title
+channel           +iconv             +packages          -toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +user_commands
-clientserver      +job               -perl              +vertsplit
-clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +virtualedit
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +visual
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +visualextra
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +viminfo
+comments          +libcall           -python            +vreplace
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +wildignore
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +wildmenu
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +windows
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +writebackup
+cursorshape       -lua               -ruby              -X11
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        -xfontset
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -xim
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -xpm
-dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       -xsmp
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +statusline        -xterm_clipboard
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xterm_save
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +syntax            
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/opt/VIM/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vem        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl   -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
```

Comment: might depend on plugins. So are you using any? Try first with `vim --clean` and also see the faq: http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5

Comment: yes. I do. I have quite a few. `onedark`, `javascript, rust, python and linters` along with syntax highlighters. Oh my, I should now try finding by `uninstall/install`, shouldn't I?

Comment: Very likely that a plugin (linter or other external process) is the root cause; yes, try and debug w/&w/o plugins

Comment: wondering, is there any stacktrace methods from `vim` side to track the plugin utilization? I could see couple of python processes running (probably YCM) besides that my suspicion is on the theme (palenight). The issue has started only after installing `palenight`. How likely is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up with the suggestions from `Christian`, I have found the plugin that causes this issue. It is `YouCompleteMe` Plugin that creates a new log file after 30 minutes of inactivity in any of vim instance.